# Generate bigrams with NLTK

Tags: python, nltk, n-gram

I am trying to produce a bigram list of a given sentence for example, if I type,

```
    To be or not to be
```

I want the program to generate

```
     to be, be or, or not, not to, to be
```

I tried the following code but just gives me

```
<generator object bigrams at 0x0000000009231360>
```

This is my code:

```
    import nltk
    bigrm = nltk.bigrams(text)
    print(bigrm)
```

So how do I get what I want? I want a list of combinations of the words like above (to be, be or, or not, not to, to be).

Comment: Try: `list(bigrm)`

Comment: Just cause I love the code: [Here](http://locallyoptimal.com/blog/2013/01/20/elegant-n-gram-generation-in-python/) is a nice NLTK-independent bigram-oneliner.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

[`nltk.bigrams()`](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.html#nltk.util.bigrams) returns an iterator (a generator specifically) of bigrams. If you want a list, pass the iterator to `list()`. It also expects a sequence of items to generate bigrams from, so you have to split the text before passing it (if you had not done it):

```
bigrm = list(nltk.bigrams(text.split()))
```

To print them out separated with commas, you could (in python 3):

```
print(*map(' '.join, bigrm), sep=', ')
```

If on python 2, then for example:

```
print ', '.join(' '.join((a, b)) for a, b in bigrm)
```

Note that just for printing you do not need to generate a list, just use the iterator.

Answer (score 14):

The following code produce a `bigram` list for a given sentence

```
>>> import nltk
>>> from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
>>> text = "to be or not to be"
>>> tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(text)
>>> bigrm = nltk.bigrams(tokens)
>>> print(*map(' '.join, bigrm), sep=', ')
to be, be or, or not, not to, to be
```

Answer (score 2):

Quite late, but this is another way.

```
>>> from nltk.util import ngrams
>>> text = "I am batman and I like coffee"
>>> _1gram = text.split(" ")
>>> _2gram = [' '.join(e) for e in ngrams(_1gram, 2)]
>>> _3gram = [' '.join(e) for e in ngrams(_1gram, 3)]
>>> 
>>> _1gram
['I', 'am', 'batman', 'and', 'I', 'like', 'coffee']
>>> _2gram
['I am', 'am batman', 'batman and', 'and I', 'I like', 'like coffee']
>>> _3gram
['I am batman', 'am batman and', 'batman and I', 'and I like', 'I like coffee']
```